# Dynamically setting an id to a button in js

Tags: javascript, button, indexing

I have a table that is populated by firebase. I have buttons that are attached to each row in the table. The problem is I dont know how to distinguish the buttons between one another.

in ios you would do this in a cellForRowAtIndex

```
 UIButton *aButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:aFrame];
 aButton.tag= A_BUTTON_TAG_CONSTANT + indexPath.row;
```

Then in your selector you would determine which button in the tableView was pressed and you could handle the action on the right part of data. 
In my web app I have the following.

```
 function myCreateFunction(order) {
var table = document.getElementById("ordersTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = order.addressType;
cell2.innerHTML = order.totalPrice;
for(i in order.address) {
  var aCell=row.insertCell(i+3);
  aCell.innerHTML=order.address[i];
console.log (i, order.address[i])
}
 var timeSince=makeTimeStamp(order.timeStamp);
 var row = table.rows[index]; 
cell3.innerHTML=timeSince;
cell4.innerHTML = '<input id="Button" type="button"  value="click"     onclick="return btntest_onclick()" />';

}
```

This method is called everytime a "child_added" event occurs. So the table grows like a stack with the most recent on the top. So the newest snapshot would be populated in row 0 and the oldest would be in row n, where n is number of snapshots.

Now I would like to be able to know which button was pressed in the table so I can go to another page and show details regarding the post. So how can I know which button was pressed and which row is being targeted?

Comment: As the rows are populated add the index to the id then you can use the JavaScript this. to select what id was pressed. <input id="Button'+index+'".....

Answer (score 0):

In your function keep the code except last line, i.e. -

```
var table = document.getElementById("ordersTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = order.addressType;
cell2.innerHTML = order.totalPrice;
for(i in order.address) {
  var aCell=row.insertCell(i+3);
  aCell.innerHTML=order.address[i];
  console.log (i, order.address[i])
}
 var timeSince=makeTimeStamp(order.timeStamp);
 var row = table.rows[index]; 
 cell3.innerHTML=timeSince;
```

Then write this:

## edited

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  myclickFunction(row);
}, false);
cell4.appendChild(button);
```

Your myClickFunction will be as following:

```
//this function will be called for the each cell4 button and would contain that cell's row info
function myclickFunction(clickedRow){
  //do something with the row info of clicked button and form payload for rest api
  var payload = formPayload(clickedRow); //the payload formed from the clicked row
  sendAjaxOfThisRow(payload);
}
```

This way you won't need to add id and do unnecessary DOM manipulation afterwards.

Comment: Ok. This definitely cleans it up. However, how do i know which row button was clicked?

Comment: Why do you have to know which button was clicked? Because as far as I understand this, you only need row or cell info in the callback function of click. So we can make things declarative rather than dynamically getting info. I am editing the callback for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually found the solution. I did use Vineet's solution for the button. However his solution was incomplete. The main thing i wished to achieve is to access the information in the table row which the button was selected. It was achieved this way. in my button's selector i have the following

```
function myclickFunction()
{
var idex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
var idex1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
var idex2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
var idex3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
//alert(document.getElementById("ordersTable").rows[0].innerHTML);
alert('<p><b>index:</b>' + idex + ' ' + idex1 + ' ' + idex2 + ' ' +   idex3 + '</p>');
}
```

I found this solution somewhere else. Although it doesnt really create an analagous to iOS; it is the intended behaviour. it seems to me the call closest gets the parent in some way. this retrieves the table rows text and solves the problem. hope this helps someone